# OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-volley, handler

I am making an tracking application where i track the bus location. I want to make it realtime so i have to call api every second. If i make 3 second interval then it works fine but changing to 1 second crashing the app. I also added `largeheap = true` in Manifest but doesn't work in this case. I also added catch for OutOfMemoryException but still it crashes. How can i handle this handler?

**Request**

```
public void GetChildLocation(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LAST_COORDINATE_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                JSONObject location = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(location.getString("latitude")),Double.parseDouble(location.getString("longitude")));
                if (latlng != null) {
                    double PI = 3.14159;
                    //Source
                    double lat1 = latlng.latitude* PI / 180;
                    double lng1 = latlng.longitude* PI / 180;
                    // destination
                    double lat2 = newLatLng.latitude* PI / 180;
                    double lng2 = newLatLng.longitude* PI / 180;
                    double dLon = (lng2 - lng1);
                    double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
                    double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
                    double brng = Math.toDegrees((Math.atan2(y, x)));
                    brng = (brng + 360) % 360;

                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newLatLng));
                    animateMarker(mCurrentLocationMarker, newLatLng, (float) brng, false);
                    latlng = newLatLng;
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    GetChildLocation();
                }
            },1000);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("track_id",trackId);
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers = super.getHeaders();
            if (headers == null || headers.equals(Collections.<String, String>emptyMap())){
                headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            }
            MyApp.get().addSessionCookie(headers);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    if (getContext() != null) {
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            RequestQueue queue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
            queue1.add(stringRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: digimkey.example.digimkey_4.dmk_parent_app, PID: 21684
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
    at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:730)
    at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:128)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:91)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:67)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:102)
    at digimkey.example.digimkey_4.dmk_parent_app.TrackMap.GetChildLocation(TrackMap.java:571)
    at digimkey.example.digimkey_4.dmk_parent_app.TrackMap$4$1.run(TrackMap.java:539)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, under normal conditions, you shouldn't be catching an `OutOfMemoryError` or any `Error` subclass **at all**, take a look at `Error`'s [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) which explains it nicely:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.

As for your request code, it looks like you're allocating a lot of stuff every time the request is fired, especially `Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());`, you can take a look at the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue#singleton) to learn how to reuse volley's request queue and how to implement a basic cache.

You can go a little bit further and also reuse the `StringRequest` itself without creating a new one every time while reusing values for `getParams` and `getHeader` without allocating new ones each time.

It might look like this, but again, the whole approach doesn't seem right and might be a good idea to reconsider you app's architecture.

```
class YourClass {

    private static final int REQUEST_DELAY_MS = 1000;

    // Assuming you have initialize those somewhere
    private final Map params;
    private final Map headers;
    private final Handler handler;

    private final RequestQueue queue;

    private final StringRequest updateLocationRequest =  
        = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "some url", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final String response) {
            // handle your result here
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(final VolleyError error) {
            // handle error here
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return headers;
        }
    };

    // It's actually better to provide a RequestQueue here or use a singleton, 
    // but for sake of example doing it here
    public YourClass(@NonNull final Context context) {
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        // You put the respective params here
        headers = new HashMap<>();
        params = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void getChildLocation() {
        queue.add(updateLocationRequest);

        handler.postDelayed(getChildLocation(), REQUEST_DELAY_MS);
    }
}
```

Anyway, is it really necessary to call the API every second (or every three seconds) to update the bus location? I mean, does the bus change it's physical location a lot in these three seconds?

Comment: Yes it is needed to send request every second.

Comment: And it is not crashing when i start activity. It crashes after some time when RequestQueue get full.

Comment: Check the update. You app crashes not because the queue is full but because you are allocating a lot of unnecessary objects often